# jquery detect when click events bound and ready

Tags: jquery, binding

The following piece of code binds a click handler to approximately 30 anchors on a relatively large/complex page, and it's been problematic in that it seems to take a few seconds to finish binding everything up. (I'm guessing.)

```
    var fiveNavs = $('[id$=nav]').find('a:not(.exception)');
    fiveNavs.click(function(){ 
        // doingness
        return false;
    });
```

There must be some way for me to look at how long it's taking, or at least to figure out when it's ready for action. (If I click one of these links too soon, it behaves strangely, but if I wait a few seconds after the script has finished loading (via .getScript) it works perfectly.)

I've been looking into various ways of detecting then a click function is bound, but nothing has worked for me so far. If at all possible, I'd like to know how long it takes from the moment this piece of code starts to the moment everything is bound up and ready.

At the very least what I'd like to figure out is (pseudo code):

```
   $.when( fiveNavs.allBoundUpAndReady() )
    .then( alert('bam') );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should look at binding to a container object with `$("#container).on(...)`

Comment: Well, I'm binding to five containers, each with id's that contain the letters 'nav'.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may be binding the click event prior to the DOM being completely rendered.

I recommend you wrap your click handler in jQuery's document ready method (see below):

```
$(function(){
    var fiveNavs = $('[id$=nav]').find('a:not(.exception)');
    fiveNavs.click(function(){ 
       // doingness
       return false;
    });
}):
```

Comment: Nah you misread me. I'm not the brightest candle on the cake, but I'm not utterly useless, either.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually binding to the individual anchors, but your selector is wrong to find the five containers. Try this

```
 $('[id*="nav"]').on('click','a:not(.exception)',function(){
   // Do something here
 });
```

This binds to the containers with `id` containing 'nav', but filters to the specified anchors.   This should bind to just five elements rather than thirty.